# Toolkit is not fiving the password prompt for One plus Seagate password protected external drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, passwords, prompt

I have a laptop and I used to manually copy files to an external disk via copy-paste. That disk is password protected and the seagate toolkit would ask for a password.

This suddenly no longer works. I do not know if that is due to a software problem or due to a hardware failure.

I have logged out and I tried logging in again. In the seagate toolskit all the options from the toolkit are gone and the disk shows as locked.

I have attempted to uninstall and re-install the toolkit innumerable number of times by restarting the laptop it doesn't work, the space on the disk that is visible is 512 MB.

Can someone help me understand how to access my data?

Comment: First, please use the EDIT button and fix up your question to make it more clear. Second, what do you mean when you say you "used your hard disk to manually copy files on the external disk"? What hard disk? What external disk? Third, it sounds like the external drive is dead.

Comment: What "toolkit" are you using? It sounds like some proprietary [Seagate software](https://www.seagate.com/support/software/toolkit/)? Also, as a general comment, the last external Seagate drive I owned suddenly stopped working one day. It wasn't even recognized by Windows. Some control or interface in the drive housing had died and I had to remove the hard disk from that external enclosure and mount it with a hard drive docking station to get access to the data again.

Comment: Thanks, music2myear, I have corrected my question,

Comment: Thanks, Anaksunaman

Comment: Thanks, Anaksunaman  You are right!  I wish I could load the picture.  When I connect the drive through the toolkit, it asks me to load Seagate secure. However, "Under Seagate Secure"' on the Seagate website, (for my product) (the one plus with password) it is not showing any link to download the toolkit, it just says that "Not available in all countries"  I had deleted the original toolkit as it became dysfunctional, and the new one I downloaded from the Seagate website, is not functional on this external drive. Please help